# Can I get my question reopened?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question at

[Can an incorporeal creature occupy the same space as another creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86270/incorporeal-creatures-and-solid-creatures)

And a mod closed it as "too broad". It clearly is not too broad and there is already an answer to it and a comment lead me to a book that can answer it even better and completely in a short space, but I can't even put that answer there now. (it also invalidates the current only answer, which I foolishly upvoted at first and now cannot downvote)
The mod told me to post here, otherwise I wouldn't for a simple issue like this.

Comment: Related 1 question, 1 post meta: [1 post - 1 question , is it a rule or a guideline or what?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/1-post-1-question-is-it-a-rule-or-a-guideline-or-what)

Comment: This question has been split, edited, and reopened.

Answer (score 6):

This question is still composed of questions that are different enough that they should be asked separately.

1. What space does a creature occupy, and can incorporeal creatures share space with a corporeal and/or incorporeal creature?

While "what space does a creature occupy" is technically a different question, it's tightly related and small, so it would probably pass muster.

2. Can incorporeal creatures perform combat maneuvers like Bull Rush and Overrun on corporeal creatures?

This question has no relation to the other question except "but incorporeal", so it's not a good candidate for combining.

3. Do incorporeal creatures provoke AoOs from opponents?  Can they Tumble to avoid them?

I get that AoOs may be provoked from moving into a space, and/or from a combat maneuver, so this is probably why you're lumping it all together, but they are separate issues that will have nontrivial answers unto themselves.

4. A list of random other mini-questions.  How thick of a wall can an incorporeal creature pass through?  Can an incorporeal creature squeeze? etc.

The one question per post guidance is already proven with response to your question - as the first answer tries to answer you, but of course only answers a couple of these widely ranging questions. It is for your own good, and to get you answers to the real problems you're having, that you should break it up into more targeted questions than "tell me everything about how incorporeal works in every movement and combat case please."

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that One Question, One Post not only serves OP better, but also future users and viewers? While we certainly want to solve the problem at hand, it's also nice if we can do so in a way that's more-likely to be ultimately useful.

Comment: Probably in the generic "why one question" meta.  I'm not inclined to spend a lot more time here though.

Comment: Fair--I just saw that other one; fear I'm catching up to these LIFO, not FIFO.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see it was originally closed as it contained multiple questions. Reading your recent edit though, this still seems to be an issue because of the 'side issue' you include at the end of the question.

Comment: Yours contains 12 questions, that's a lot. I would advice you to re-write it so there is less interrogations so it would be easier to see what actually matters.

Comment: @Simanos You may find the answers on [this question](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5904/4398) and [others](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6241/4398) [like it](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5266/4398) helpful. (And please, don't use inflammatory language to describe things you disagree with. It makes folks less likely to take your legitimate concerns seriously.)

Comment: @BESW nobody has yet pointed me to the rule that says one single (arbitrarily defined) question per post. Too Broad does not mention it. Is it an actual rule somewhere or a guideline or what?

Comment: @Simanos Perhaps that'd be a good meta question, then.

Comment: Also, I can just ask "How do incorporeal creatures work?". It's one question and encompasses all my little hidden questions, or I can make 12 question posts and ask a single disjointed part question in each without context of the full situation. It just feels wrong and inefficient. It just seems better to post all the cloudy for me things about Incorporeality in one question to have them together for me and readers.

Comment: @Simanos we get that you think that, honestly, we do. The problem is that the site policy is to close questions with multiple subquestion, as has been stated many times. We get that you disagree with this policy, but you stating repeatedly that you disagree with it is not going to change it

Comment: Related meta: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/1-post-1-question-is-it-a-rule-or-a-guideline-or-what

Comment: @simanos: "pedantic and arbitrary" is indeed inflammatory language, as is arguing in the comments with everyone who tries to help you on every meta question.  You need to tone it down now.  Some comments have been removed.

Comment: How is pedantic and arbitrary inflammatory? They are statements of fact. Language is a complex structure. You can make single sentence that appears to be a single question, but is in fact asking about several things. Personal interpretation is required to judge if a question is multi-part or single part with several cases needing to be investigated. I protest at your veiled threats and unfair removal of my comments that nobody complained about.

Comment: @Wibbs can you point me to that written policy? I didn't state repeatedly that I disagreed with it, I stated it once maybe twice. What is your pass the bar limit for question parts to be too related to each other so it is OK to be in the same question and what's the limit for not being related enough?

Comment: Yes, of course there is always personal interpretation involved.  Yes, calling people's thinking about the site pedantic is inflammatory - if you didn't know that, I'm telling you now. My threat is not veiled - Be Nice.  Using inflammatory language and badgering is Not Nice.  Tone it down.

Comment: You removed comments on the one answer to Incorporeal question that a user found rules in Libris Mortis and the answer giver said it was OK for me to edit his answer with more info because he didn't have access to the book. Is it still OK for me to edit the answer? I'm confused with your moderating

Comment: 1. The other question is on hold, so please don't "stealth answer" by editing existing answers.  Once that's off, sure, editing stuff into answers/adding other answers is fine.

Comment: 2. Now I'm going to delete every comment in which you say pedantic and arbitrary until you get the point about not using inflammatory language.

Comment: Is this really proper mod behavior? Words are words, it matters how you use them, also I wasn't going to stealth answer, the user who made the Answer made a comment (that you deleted for NO reason) that he wanted me to edit his answer with this info (P.S. i don't think i even said aggressive once).

Comment: @Simanos Yes, it matters how words are used. mxyzplk is informing you in a remarkably gentle way that how you've used them is against site policy. That's not something you can or should be arguing with; please just take it as information that's helpful in changing how you use words here. Edit: This may be a translation problem, too: “arbitrary” is usually a neutral word in English (though context can make it insulting), but “pedantic” is almost always used as an insult in English (though careful context can make it not); both are coming off as attacks/insults in those comments.

Comment: Maybe it's because I frequent forums with people who discuss philosophical matters who take pride in calling themselves pedantic on occasion (sometimes as a joke, sometimes seriously if the topic is complex enough). I think the words pedantic and arbitrary are factual and I was describing a rule not a person. If you say a certain king was arbitrary in handing out justice, killing both guilty and innocent prisoners without reason, then yes it is "insulting"to him, but if you say a Law that prisoners  roll a die to see if they live or die is arbitrary then you're not offending any person.

Comment: @Simanos In the context of a community that use the terms in a deliberately neutral and often self-applied way, yeah, “pedantic” isn't going to be an insult. Now that you know that this community isn't one of those exceptions to the norm, normal social meaning of the word (i.e., it's usually an insult, or used to indirectly insult by applying it to someone's statements) should be kept in mind instead.

Comment: It's not an insult though if it's used factually and about a "rule" and not a person.

Comment: @Simanos If someone says "Hey, I find that word choice offensive," it's totally fine to say, "Sorry, I didn't mean any offense." But saying "You're wrong to be offended," is dismissing the person's own experience as invalid. As you've recently learnt, you were NOT describing a clearly defined rule as pedantic: you were describing a specific individual's application of a general principle as pedantic. You didn't know, but now you do.

Comment: @Simanos I looked at it, and I edited it in hopes that it will attract re-open votes.  You've packed a lot into the question, but I do like that you put the bottom line up front, and then added the rest for context to illustrate why the problem/question arose.  I think it would be beneficial to add in the link to the other questions you had on incorporeal creatures.

Comment: @Simanos Like you were told last time, if you have a problem with the moderators and the mods have rejected your appeals, your only choice is to contact the CMs. Littering the site with gripes is *not* an officially-OK fallback when mods and CMs have all refused your appeal. You've been told this before. Let me remind you that this is **official** again: **no more complaining in comments about mod “harassment” after the CMs rejected your appeal**. We're just doing our job. If you don't like it, try appealing to CMs again instead of adding Be Nice–violating litter we are obliged to clean up.